R- output of function prints but cannot be stored
I am new to programming and I am creating a program that evaluates all possible paths of length 48 through a 6*8 grid of numbers (padded by 0s) allowing vertical,horizontal,and diaganol movement. I have successfully made a function that creates and prints unique paths exactly how I want them except I cannot figure out how to save them for later reference. Optimally, I would like to be able to call a specefic list by the number of the iteration where it was created(eg the ith unique path would could be found with paths[["i"]]).
Here is my code:
`numbmatrix <- rbind(c(rep(0,times=8)),cbind(c(rep(0,times=8)),matrix(1:48,nrow=8,ncol=6),c(rep(0,times=8))),c(rep(0,times=8)))
possmoves <- cbind(rbind(1,-1),rbind(1,0),rbind(1,1),rbind(0,1),rbind(-1,1),rbind(-1,0),rbind(-1,-1),rbind(0,-1))

oneawayfrom <- function(startrow,startcol){
  visited <- matrix(0,nrow=10,ncol=8)
  oneaway <- list()
  for (i in 1:8){
    dx <- possmoves[1,i]
    dy <- possmoves[2,i]
    nextmove <- numbmatrix[startrow + dy,startcol + dx]
    if (nextmove == 0 | visited[startrow + dy,startcol + dx] != 0 ){next}
    if (visited[startrow + dy,startcol + dx] == 0 && nextmove !=0){
      visited[startrow + dy,startcol + dx] <- 1
      oneaway[[length(oneaway)+1]]<- nextmove
    }
  }
  return(oneaway)
}
options <- list()
for (i in 2:9){
  for (n in 2:7){
    adjacent <- oneawayfrom(i,n)
    cell_key <- as.character(numbmatrix[i,n])
    options[[cell_key]] <- adjacent
  }
}
paths <- list()
path_counter <- 1
pathmaker <- function(current_path){
if (length(current_path) == 48) {
    path_name <- as.character(path_counter)
    path_counter <<- path_counter + 1
    paths[[path_name]] <- current_path
    print(paste(paths, collapse=""))
  }
last_element <- current_path[length(current_path)]
for(i in seq_along(options[[as.character(last_element)]])){
  adjacent_number <- options[[as.character(last_element)]][i]
  if (!(adjacent_number %in% current_path)){
    new_path <- pathmaker(c(current_path,adjacent_number))
  }
} 
return(paths)
}
storepaths <- pathmaker(current_path=c(numbmatrix[2,2]))`

So, the problem lies in the last function, and particularly in storepaths. I want storepaths to be a list of lists that stores every unique path of length 48 found by the function pathmaker, and I want each list of storepaths to have a unique name corresponding to the itertation of pathmaker when it was created. When I enter storepaths it prints exactly how I want it to:
1\] "list(1, 9, 17, 25, 33, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 40, 32, 39, 31, 38, 30, 37, 29, 36, 28, 35, 27, 34, 26, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 16, 8, 15, 7, 14, 6, 13, 5, 12, 4, 11, 18, 10, 3, 2)"
\[1\] "list(1, 9, 17, 25, 33, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 40, 32, 39, 31, 38, 30, 37, 29, 36, 28, 35, 27, 34, 26, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 16, 8, 15, 7, 14, 6, 13, 5, 12, 4, 11, 18, 10, 2, 3)"
\[1\] "list(1, 9, 17, 25, 33, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 40, 32, 39, 31, 38, 30, 37, 29, 36, 28, 35, 27, 34, 26, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 16, 8, 15, 7, 14, 6, 13, 5, 12, 4, 11, 3, 2, 10, 18)"

However, I think I am misunderstanding how return works because after I run storepaths <- pathmaker(current_path=c(numbmatrix[2,2])) (and stop it after it has generated some lists), none of the data is saved to it and it is just an empty list. How can I correctly store the results of the function and how can I make it so that each list is referentiable? Thank you!

What do you mean “and stop it after it has generated some lists”? If you terminate execution, the function won’t return anything, which is why you just have the empty list you initialized. If your function runs infinitely, you’ll have to build a better stopping condition into your code.

You’re also using objects defined in the global environment inside your function — not great practice in general, but I suspect might really be wreaking havoc here because your function is recursive. You should instead have pathmaker() accept a paths argument, and pass it the paths list on the initial and recursive calls.
